# My old iTunes library isn't appearing in iTunes on my new PC

Tags: itunes, windows

I recently set up my new PC (Windows 8) and installed iTunes. I then moved the `iTunes` folder from my old PC to my new PC. I set the iTunes library path in Preferences to that folder. But when I launch iTunes, none of the music shows up.

I also tried copying across the entire `/music/iTunes` directory, but it didn't work.

Comment: are you sure you copied the correct folder? On the old computer, you may have a folder that iTunes created when it was installed, but you changed that a long time ago and forgot.  Make sure the folder you copied actually contains the music.

Answer (score 1):

The iTunes library on PC is stored in one of the following locations, depending on the version of Windows in use.

> Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Music\iTunes\
>
> Windows Vista: C:\Users\username\Music\iTunes\
>
> Windows 7/8: C:\Users\username\My Music\iTunes\

What version of Windows was in use on your old PC? It's also possible that an older version of iTunes was in use on the old PC and iTunes is somehow not recognizing it on the new PC.